Simple and open source or free tool to add captions to GIF images
Can you recommend any simple open-source tool to add captions to GIF images, for example a tool that would allow to create a meme?
Alternatively, a non-open-source but still free tool would be good too.
The tool should be as simple as possible (no Photoshop-like tools like GIMP), for example something like MS Paint (or kolourpaint, which is an open source alternative) that just shows the GIF image (or its frames) and allows to insert a textbox that would be visible in all frames of the GIF image.
There are plenty of web apps and online tools like this on Internet, but apparently it's very difficult to find a tool that can be installed locally and used offline.

@Destroy666 I am a MacOS user, therefore I cannot test the ScreenToGIF solution as it is only for Windows. About gifcurry, it seems easier and more reliable to install on Linux, but on MacOS it can only be installed by a script that also installs lots of packages for such a simple purpose, which seems an overkill, and it requests admin rights (why??), therefore I would have to trust the developers very much. I still consider it useful based on the information I found about it (in fact I upvoted your answer), but I was waiting for some time to see if anyone else suggests further alternatives.

@Destroy666 I just double checked the official website for gifcurry, and they say "Eventually there will be a Homebrew formula so installing Gifcurry on the Mac will be super easy.". If the Homebrew package will be accepted by the Homebrew community (i.e. it won't be just a custom "tap" to be trusted separately), or if the Homebrew package won't require admin rights (like almost all Homebrew packages), then installing it on MacOS may become much easier and more reliable.

You should mark the system in your question if you are primarily looking for one and not at all willing to use it on Windows.

You could try gifcurry - it meets your criteria of being open source. Of simplicity likely too, but that's subjective. But it's advertised for memes.


Alternatively, for Windows operating systems there is also ScreenToGif.
While the main focus is screen capturing animations, it has a pretty decent builtin editor, which among other editing features can add text, captions and simple shapes or annotations to all or arbitrary selections of frames.

